# Is it possible to get https prestashop docker-compose without using nginx or other simiraly dockers?

Tags: linux, nginx, docker-compose, https, prestashop

i did a prestashop with mysql docker-compose, and my questions is like in subject.
Instalation guide from prestashop docker - https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop
asked me if i want secured website, i choose yes. After success installation i went to website by their recommendation and got following error:

[image]

It is not a problem to do it, just asking is it needed, because i wanted to avoid apache or nginx in my service.

Docker-compose file and etc files are not needed to be shown by me, cuz everything works. I just want to know that answer.

If you can send link to some articles or something like that i would be greatfull. I am sure that exist more ppl with this question, don't know, and maybe unecressary using nginx.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Prestashop/prestashop docker has an apache and php inside.
To use ssl, just find apache folder inside docker container. There you need to generate or copy/paste your certs.

So apache service and nginx is not needed. If you want to configure apache vhost, find 001.default.conf file, this is vhost config to setup apache.